# Shortcut method for proving equivalence relations

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

> Define the relation R on N*N by: (x,y)R(z,w) if and only if x-z =
>   w-y. Check whether R is an equivalence relation. Explain your answer

My teacher answer is:

> Using the shortcut method: (a,b)R(c,d) if and only if f(a,b)=(c,d)
>   where f(a,b) = a+b

Here also:

> Define the relation R on N, by mRn if 3|m-n (a) Is R an equivalence
>   relation? If so, what are its equivalence classes?

My teacher answer is:

> Using the shortcut method: mRn if and only if f(m)=f(n) where f(m) = m
>   % 3

I didn't understand how she proved it this way! I usually prove it by proving if it's reflexive symmetric and transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the second question all your teacher has done is to show that two pairs are related on R iff they are congruent to each other modulo 3. I am guessing the teacher had previously taught you that congruence modulo n is an equivalence relation on the set of natural numbers.

I am also willing to guess that maybe she taught you that $(x,y)R(a,b) \iff x + y = a +b$ is an equivalence relation. So by the shortcut method I think she simply means transforming the relation into something she had already taught was an equivalence relation.

But if I were you I would just prove they are symmetric, reflexive and transitive. It is not that difficult and would look much better.